CloudFormation: DatasetType: Actions and Action_Interactions is not a valid enum value
In Amazon Personalize, I'm having issues creating a Dataset of Actions and Action Interactions using Cloud Formation.
The template I'm using looks something like this:
{
  "Resources": {
    "sapersonalizedatasetgroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::DatasetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "sa_personalize"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_datasetgroup"
      }
    },
    "sapersonalizeactionsschema": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::Schema",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "sa_personalize_actions",
        "Schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"Actions\", \"namespace\": \"com.amazonaws.personalize.schema\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"ACTION_ID\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"VALUE\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"]}, {\"name\": \"MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"categorical\": true}, {\"name\": \"CREATION_TIMESTAMP\", \"type\": \"long\"}, {\"name\": \"REPEAT_FREQUENCY\", \"type\": [\"long\", \"null\"]}], \"version\": \"1.0\"}"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_actions_schema"
      }
    },
    "sapersonalizeinteractionsschema": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::Schema",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "sa_personalize_interactions",
        "Schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"Interactions\", \"namespace\": \"com.amazonaws.personalize.schema\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"USER_ID\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"ITEM_ID\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"EVENT_TYPE\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"EVENT_VALUE\", \"type\": [\"float\", \"null\"]}, {\"name\": \"LOCATION\", \"type\": \"string\", \"categorical\": true}, {\"name\": \"DEVICE\", \"type\": [\"string\", \"null\"], \"categorical\": true}, {\"name\": \"TIMESTAMP\", \"type\": \"long\"}, {\"name\": \"IMPRESSION\", \"type\": \"string\"}], \"version\": \"1.0\"}"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_interactions_schema"
      }
    },
    "sapersonalizeactioninteractionsschema": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::Schema",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "sa_personalize_actioninteractions",
        "Schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"ActionInteractions\", \"namespace\": \"com.amazonaws.personalize.schema\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"USER_ID\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"ACTION_ID\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"EVENT_TYPE\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"TIMESTAMP\", \"type\": \"long\"}], \"version\": \"1.0\"}"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_actioninteractions_schema"
      }
    },
    "sapersonalizeactionsdataset": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::Dataset",
      "Properties": {
        "DatasetGroupArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "sapersonalizedatasetgroup",
            "DatasetGroupArn"
          ]
        },
        "DatasetType": "Actions",
        "Name": "sa_personalize_actions",
        "SchemaArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["sapersonalizeactionsschema", "SchemaArn"]
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_actions_dataset"
      }
    },
    "sapersonalizeinteractionsdataset": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::Dataset",
      "Properties": {
        "DatasetGroupArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "sapersonalizedatasetgroup",
            "DatasetGroupArn"
          ]
        },
        "DatasetType": "Interactions",
        "Name": "sa_personalize_interactions",
        "SchemaArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "sapersonalizeinteractionsschema",
            "SchemaArn"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_interactions_dataset"
      }
    },
    "sapersonalizeactioninteractionsdataset": {
      "Type": "AWS::Personalize::Dataset",
      "Properties": {
        "DatasetGroupArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "sapersonalizedatasetgroup",
            "DatasetGroupArn"
          ]
        },
        "DatasetType": "Action_Interactions",
        "Name": "sa_personalize_actioninteractions",
        "SchemaArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "sapersonalizeactioninteractionsschema",
            "SchemaArn"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "SaPersonalizeStack/sa_personalize_actioninteractions_dataset"
      }
    }
  }
}


Despite the documentation saying that the DatasetType can have the following values:

Interactions
Items
Users
Actions
Action_Interactions

Cloud Formation throws the following errors:
Properties validation failed for resource sapersonalizeactioninteractionsdataset with message: [#/DatasetType: Action_Interactions is not a valid enum value]

and
Properties validation failed for resource sapersonalizeactionsdataset with message: [#/DatasetType: Actions is not a valid enum value]

In the errors, it says that Actions and Action_Interactions are not valid enum values.
Is it not yet supported or am I missing something?

According to the registry schema, these are the allowed enum values:
"DatasetType": {
      "description": "The type of dataset",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "Interactions",
        "Items",
        "Users"
      ],
      "maxLength": 256
    },

I'll check to see what's up with the other values being displayed in the docs. This is definitely confusing.

Thank you very much Eric.
Do you have an ETA of the other types?
Or would you recommend using boto3 for the moment?

The documentation is not correct and will be corrected. The NBA dataset types are currently not supported in CloudFormation. No ETA for when they will be added. Apologies for the confusion. A custom resource would be one workaround.
